# W2k Server: delete specific users by console

Tags: user-management, console, windows-2000

I want to delete specific user profiles in win2k-Server.
I thought I could achieve that with [microsofts Delprof](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5405). But there I cant specificly declare userXY. So is there an other console way to delete users in win2k server

EDIT: DelProf2 isnt working with W2k

cheers Simon

Answer (score 1):

stupid me, sorry for that question

```
net user USERNAME /delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, DelProf2 will allow you to specify the profile you want to remove.

[DelProf2](http://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/)

Comment: i knew that but delprof2 is working just wuth this versions of Windows it works: XP/2003/Vista/2008/7/2008 R2/8